# Eclipselink MOXy eclipselink,media type propertyException, help on setup

Tags: eclipselink, moxy

I'm trying to do a simple test for eclipselink's JSON to JAXB object capabilities.
I originally planned on using moxy to generate json, and then again using it to marshal out to objects, however attempting to set the eclipselink.media-type and the eclipselink.json.include-root properties both are throwing a PropertyException.
I'm sure it's because I've set something up wrong.

here is my main method:
(i have  a package moxyTest, with a single Foo class that has two string values)

```
        JAXBContext jc = org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
                .createContext(new Class[] { moxyTest.Foo.class }, null);
        Marshaller marsh = jc.createMarshaller();
        Foo firstObject = new Foo("value1", "value2");
        marsh.setProperty("eclipselink.media-type", "application/json");
        marsh.marshal(firstObject, System.out);
```

I didn't bother with a jaxb.properties file since i'm specifying the eclipselink one explicitly, but I also tried adding one and it didn't do anything.
The curious thing is that it's not throwing a propertyNotFoundException, but rather just a plain PropertyException.

with that being said, on a side note, I know moxy has  object->xml and object-> json, is there a fast way to directly json->xml or vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you are using EclipseLink 2.4.0 or newer your code will work as is:

**Domain Model (Foo)**

```java
package moxyTest;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Foo {

    private String a;
    private String b;

    public Foo() {
    }

    public Foo(String a, String b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

}
```

**Demo**

```java
package moxyTest;

import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
                .createContext(new Class[] { moxyTest.Foo.class }, null);
        Marshaller marsh = jc.createMarshaller();
        Foo firstObject = new Foo("value1", "value2");
        marsh.setProperty("eclipselink.media-type", "application/json");
        marsh.marshal(firstObject, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
{"foo":{"a":"value1","b":"value2"}}
```